# $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a quotient of a group

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

I am looking for a locally compact group $G$ with a closed subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $G$ does decompose into a semidirect and/or direct product which possesses $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a component.

Comment: I suppose you mean *does not compose*.

Comment: What is meant by "in a bijection relation with" in the context of topological groups? Do you really mean a bijection between the underlying sets (not the groups)?

Comment: I fixed that! I meant as two topological sets they are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably since the hypotheses on $G$ and $H$ are topological, one wants to require that $G / H$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, and not simply in bijection with it.

**Example 1 (Mobius transformations of the upper half-plane)** The Lie (and hence locally compact) group $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H} := \{z : \Im z > 0\}$ of the complex plane (which is, needless to say, homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$) by Mobius transformations:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \cdot z := \frac{a z + b}{c z + d};$$ since $-\mathbb{I}_2$ acts by the identity, this group action descends to [$PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group), which like $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is simple and hence does not factor as a semidirect product. Computing directly shows that the stabilizer in $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ of $i$ is isomorphic to $SO(2)$, which in particular is closed.

**Example 2 (Affine real transformations)** An example of a different (and trivial) flavor is the following: Consider the Lie group $\mathbb{R} \rtimes \mathbb{R}_+$ (again, clearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$) of orientation-preserving affine transformations of the line $\mathbb{R}$, that is, the group of maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $t \mapsto a t + b$, $a > 0$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Like all groups, it acts transitvely and freely on itself by left-multiplication, and so the stabilizer of this action contains only the identity, $t \mapsto t$. Though this topological group is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is nonabelian and hence not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^2, +)$.

Comment: Thanks for the first example, but the second example is homeomorphic to the product of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a singleton.

Comment: Having $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a factor in a semidirect product is a feature of the *group* structure, not the topological structure (for which there is no notion of semidirect product). Anyway, Example 1 suffers the same feature, as $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$, which is perhaps easiest to see by conjugating the action on $\mathbb{H}$ to let it act on the unit disk $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{C}$; in this case, we can easily parameterize the group by $\mathbb{D} \times \mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: In fact, since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, for any $G, H$ satisfying the given hypotheses, the fiber bundle $G \to G / H \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ is trivial, and in particular $G$ is homeomorphic to $H \times \mathbb{R}^2$. So, if you really do mean excluding the appearance of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a *topological* factor, there are no such examples.